# Multiple divs with the same id applying css style works same like class?

Tags: html, css

I'm confused about the class and id selection with css if i have multiple divs with same ID  changeing ID to Class does not have any effect on the result

style

```
        <style>
       #main-div
        {
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        background-color:red;
        margin:10px;

        }
    </style>








 <div id="main-div"></div>
<div id="main-div"></div>
<div id="main-div"></div>
<div id="main-div"></div>
```

Comment: Id should be unique :\

Comment: You shouldn't repeat ID. it produces invalid code and you will face serious problems when it comes to JavaScript selectors.

Comment: i know that id should be unique how css have no difference for class and id

Comment: @AshiqullahSahibzai That is different but the thing is if you are going to use javascript then you are going to be in trouble with usage of same ids.

Comment: with jquery it gets the first match element but css treat it like class

Comment: the problem is that why css does not styles the first one

Comment: Besides the effect that it is not wise to use an id multiple times (also see the other answers and comments), your code isn't working because it misses the `</style>` closing tag.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, using multiple times the same id is invalid. Never do it.

Then, in css selectors, you need to use

- ".whatever" to target classes
- "#whatever" to target ids.

Here is an example.

```
<!-- in HTML -->
<div id="identifier1"></div>
<div class="class1"></div>
<div class="class1"></div>

/* In css */
#identifier1 { /* This targets the first div */ };
.class1 { /* This targets the second and third div */ };
```

Comment: dear eloims my problem if  document has more then one element with same ID (I know it's not valid to use same id multiple times) how css treats id like class apply the same style to all elements with that id in jquery selector it only selects the first mach element

Comment: With an invalid document you have no way to ensure that all browsers will behave in the same way, whatever you do. Fix it first :). I'm pretty sure you could find a work-around to make things work, but it will just break again when another developer touches your code. Why bother?

Comment: Another solution, if you cannot change the HTML code, is not to rely on the ids, and select your DOM elements with another way in jQuery

Comment: thansk Eloims i need your short answer i was asked what is the difference  selecting element with id and class my answer was id select single element while class can be applied to many element than he told me i can apply id also to many elements.. so i last 10 marks

Comment: @Jai I'm not sure anymore about what was the asked question